# Erro ao tentar utilizar dados da api axios

Tags: javascript, react, api, axios

estou com o seguinte problema, estou tentando fazer uma api simples com Axios a parte do backend funciona normal, executa e tudo, quando to no front dou um useEffect junto ao get e coleto os dados que entra no useState chamado dados, se eu exibir somente assim no log ele mostra normal, ou seja está trazendo, mas ao tentar mapear ou utilizar como está para exibir ele mostra arreys vazios, simplesmente como se o dados não estivesse vazio.
to a 2 dias já nisso alguem pode me dar uma luz.
já tentei mapear de formas diferente mas qualquer coisa que faça ele retorna vazio e buga a pagina ficando em branco.
obs: sou novo na parte de web.

front:

```
import React,{Component, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import '../../components/cadastro/usuario/css/Nome.css';
import {SafeAreaView,StyleSheet,FlatList,Text,View, ScrollView} from "react-native";
import api from '../../Services/Api';
export default function TesteApi(){
    
    const [dados, setDados] = useState();
   
    
    useEffect(() => {
        api
        .get("/filmes")
        .then((response) => setDados(response.data))
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error("ops! deu ruim" + err);

        });
      
    }, []);

    /*  useEffect(() => {
        let newState = dados.map((e) => e); // mapear estado aqui
        setDados(newState); // atualize o estado
        console.log(newState);
     },[]);  */
    
    console.log(dados);
  
    return(
      
        <div>
        <h1>TesteApi</h1>
        <hr />
        <h3>nome: </h3>
        </div>

       /*  <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            <FlatList 
            data={dados} 
            keyExtractor={({item}) => item.id}
            renderItem={({item}) =>
            <View style={styles.titulo}>
                <Text>{item.nome}</Text>
            </View>
        
            }
            />
        </SafeAreaView>
 */
        
    )
   
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1
    },
    item: {
      backgroundColor: '#f9c2ff',
      padding: 20,
      marginVertical: 8,
      marginHorizontal: 16,
    },
    titulo: {
      fontSize: 32,
      color: 'white',
      backgroundColor: 'white',
    },
  });
```

json

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "nome": "Grey´s Anatomy",
        "foto": "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/33/39/9d/33399df9faacc5de9e3928f52fabbacf.jpg",
        "descricao": "Durante sua residência, Meredith Grey vive paixões profissionais e pessoais com seus colegas médicos em um hospital de Seattle.",
        "elenco": "Ellen Pompeo,Sandra Oh,Katherine Heigl"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "nome": "Vingadores Guerra Infinita",
        "foto": "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/63/c7/41/63c741c433aa938eadafdbd386e4e676.jpg",
        "descricao": "Em Vingadores: Guerra Infinita, Thanos (Josh Brolin) enfim chega à Terra, disposto a reunir as Joias do Infinito. Para enfrentá-lo, os Vingadores precisam unir forças com os Guardiões da Galáxia, ao mesmo tempo em que lidam com desavenças entre alguns de seus integrantes.",
        "elenco": "Tom Holland,Chris Evans,Scarlett Johansson,Robert Downey Jr" 
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "nome": "Black Summer",
        "foto": "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/e6/5a/3a/e65a3a4a13f4c0533bc1a74dd38673fb.jpg",
        "descricao": "Nos primeiros dias de um sombrio apocalipse zumbi, estranhos se unem para sobreviver e voltar para aqueles que amam.",
        "elenco": "Jaime King,Justin Chu Cary,Christine Lee"  
    }
 
   
  ]
```

index api

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const { ValidationError} = require('sequelize');
const filmes = require('./filmes.json');
const map = require('./map');

const server = express();

server.use(express.json());
server.use(cors());


server.get('/filmes', (req,res) => {
    return res.json({filmes})
});


server.listen(3010, () => {
    console.log('servidor está funcionando....')
});
```

já tentei por o map no backend já coloquei no front mas não faz o map, deixei a cima a ultima forma que tentei o map mas nada fica vazio, pode haver alguns erro me perdoem como disse sou novo.

Comment: no lugar de `setDados(response.data)` já tentou ``setDados(response.json())` ?

Comment: no caso a solução foi dado por @JhonySouza a questão era que o objeto estava vindo inteiro e não identificava o arrey.
solução setDados(response.data.filmes)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

é provável porque a resposta do back-end não está no formato que você espera. Os dados que são retornados do back-end são um objeto com uma única propriedade chamada "filmes" que contém o array de filmes.

Em seu código de front-end, você precisa atualizar a linha em que definiu o estado para:

`setDados(response.data.filmes)`

voce pode passar assim caso queira retornar so response.data:
`res.json(filmes)`

dai nao precisa passar como objeto abrindo chaves.

Isso definirá corretamente o estado para a matriz de filmes que é retornada do back-end.

Comment: *"Os dados que são retornados do back-end são um objeto com uma única propriedade chamada "filmes""* pode explicar como chegou a essa conclusão que isso é uma única propiedade chamada "filmes" ?

Comment: Para simplificar dentro do seu res.json voce esta passando como objeto, { filmes } ao menos que você queira identificar sua resposta como filmes mesmo, mas no seu caso poderia passar apenas `res.json(filmes)`.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).